# Crawling table with scrapy, site has unusual html code.

Tags: python, html, scrapy, web-crawler

first post. I appreciate any guidance, and cant wait to give back to the community.

I am trying to make a crawler using scrapy, to collect data from this table.

http://www.wikicfp.com/cfp/call?conference=machine%20learning

Specifically, the conference name, location, and date. But the table, tr, and td have no classes, and the table is within another table.

No matter how i edit my codee, it keeps giving me the whole page.

```
import scrapy


class CfpspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'cfpspider'
allowed_domains = ['http://www.wikicfp.com']
start_urls = ['http://www.wikicfp.com/cfp/call?conference=machine%20learning']

def parse(self, response):
    div = response.css("div.contsec")

    for table in div:
        print(table.css("table")[3].css.extract_first())
```

Later on, I will work on making it move on to the next page and output a csv or json, but for now im trying to get parts of this table. I have tested a few commands in  scrapy shell, but my knowledge is lacking. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way the source looks, the structure of the page is like so:

```
div class="contsec"
| center
| | form
| | | table
| | | | tr
| | | | tr
| | | | tr
| | | | | td
| | | | | | table id="the droids you are looking for"
| | | | tr
```

Edit: Try this

```
def parse(self, response):
    divs = response.css("div.contsec")
    for div in divs:
            table = div.css("table")[3]
            headers = table.css("tr")[0].css("td::text").extract()
            # print("<table headers>")
            print("\t".join(headers))
            # print("</table headers>")
            for row in table.css("tr")[1:]:
                    row_data = row.css("td::text").extract()
                    print("\t".join(row_data))
```

Comment: Thanks, but your code outputs the same result as my original code? Am i doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Same output. these two pictures show the begining and end of the shell . (Is there a better way to post the code in comments?) 
 https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah3mbRlpqEoglzAN2D0FvI2MJ6Ls    ,    https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah3mbRlpqEoglzEygpIf-9wQeXMw

Comment: i got message for response, does not match signature of base method in class.this is my class, class CfpspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):

Comment: I just noticed another problem, they split each row into two rows spanned together.

Comment: it is still giving me the entire div.contsec , im going to try remaking the scrapy package real quick

Comment: Nope...just errors. I start a project in command, cd there, create spider and input link, then i add your code to the spider. https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah3mbRlpqEoglzUrQWwqPeJCQkT7 , https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah3mbRlpqEoglzbQ9gEo3vF2Ie_7

Comment: Here's what I'm seeing https://pastebin.com/fQWszBzB. I see what you're saying now

Comment: Thank you, now to figure out the next step.

Comment: Glad to see it's working. I have a confession, it was a learning experience for me too. P.S Thanks for pinning my answer!